# I want to enable mic echo-cancellation in Ubuntu Mate, but it doesn't work. Please, help!

Tags: microphone, echo

Please help! I want to enable echo-cancellation in Ubuntu Mate. I watched Yt tutorials and answers on this forum. For solutions like this:
Edit /etc/pulse/default.pa and add the following lines to the end of the file and restart pulseaudio with pulseaudio -k
I get a command not found answer.